# Jqueryui Dialog form problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jqueryui dialog function to display my registration form. I have no problem with opening the dialog and displaying register.aspx file in the div. However I have a register button which I would like to use to save the form data into the database. But when I click to that button, it closes the dialog box and redirects the page to the register.aspx. I tried to disable usesubmitbehavior but that didn't help it completely blocks the function of the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstName.Disabled = true; // this will be replaced for db data entry. It was just to see if the function is working or not.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use OnClientClick to prevent the default behaviour of form submission upon click. If you do this you will need perform an ajax request to your server yourself.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="handleRegistrationClientSide(); return false;" runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="False"  />
```

Otherwise wrap your dialog's inner content in an update panel, and trigger it on the button to cause an async postback.

```
<div id="myDialog">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
        ...
       </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
       </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```